# I want to have a small cover image change when user clicks play on different stations/albums

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have about 24 large cover images with hovers that reveal station info and a play button. When the user click on the play button the "player" changes info to match the which one the user clicks.

Currently I have a smaller image of the cover in the "player" and it doesn't change to match the larger version.

I want the little cover image in the player to also change just like the station name and the station info do when the user clicks play so that they match the larger image

Here is the script I have so far. I don't have the cover image change in the script yet as that is what I'm trying to figure out how to link the small images because currently I have only one and its linked in the css and I have about 23 others

```
$(function(){
var station = $('.player-station'),
    record = $('.record2:first'),
    playBtns = $('.play'),
    info = $('.nprecinfo');

playBtns.click(function()
{
    var btn = $(this);
    if(btn.text() == 'STOP')
    {
        btn.text('PLAY');
        record.css({'-webkit-animation-play-state': 'paused',
                    '-moz-animation-play-state': 'paused'});
        return;
    }

    playBtns.text('PLAY');
    var album = btn.closest('.album');
    station.text(album.find('h3').text());
    info.text(album.find('.recordinfo').text());
    record.css({'-webkit-animation-play-state': 'running',
                '-moz-animation-play-state': 'running'});
    btn.text('STOP');
});
});
```

here is the html code with the small cover image. It appears inside < div id="lrvinyl" >

```
<div id="player">
            <div id="recordbox">
            <div class="record2">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="player-box">
            <div id="title-player">Now playing:</div><br><strong><span class="player-station">Groove Salad</span></strong>
 <p class="nprecinfo">A nicely chilled plate of ambient/downtempo beats and grooves.</p>
</div>
<div class="bars-box">
<div class="bars">
<div class="bar-1"></div>
<div class="bar-2"></div>
<div class="bar-3"></div>
<div class="bar-4"></div>
<div class="bar-5"></div>
<div class="bar-6"></div>
<div class="bar-7"></div>
<div class="bar-8"></div>
<div class="bar-9"></div>
<div class="bar-10"></div>
                    </div>
<div id="lrvinyl">
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
<div class="grid_3">
    <div class="album">
    <div class="record">
    </div>
```

and here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7txt3/15/

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve in the fiddle you posted?

Comment: @Nelson I want the little cover image to change just like the station name and the station info do so that they match the big image when the user clicks play

Comment: [here at fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7txt3/20/) is how I did it, with jQuery .css and adding `rel="path_to_image"` to play button link. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't see neither station info nor station name change at anytime.. they seem static.. also the cover little image already matches the big cover image, that is to say, the small is a thumbnail of the big one, please clarify a bit more and check if the fiddle you posted is the one you're talking about..

Comment: @wzazza thats not quite exactly what I wanted. I want the little cover image in the "player" to change just like the other info for the station does. You just made a image spin around like the record does :P

Comment: would help not to have to guess what you want to happen with image. Give a concise explanation of what you want, what elements need changing etc. Concept can be interpreted multiple ways

Comment: @Nelson if you look at the "player" and notice it says now playing groove salad. Then hover over the lush albumb cover and click play and notice it changes to "now playing lush..." but the tiny cover image doesn't change yet

Comment: @charlietfl I added more description to what I want to achieve

Comment: Not sure if I understand you right, but is it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7txt3/21/)

Comment: nothing "concise" about updated info. Still open to lots of guessing. My interpretation is you don't want the rotating record.

Comment: @wzazza you have gotten what I want and thank you! So what you did was just add a rel link to the play button?

Comment: @wzazza is there away to add transitions or a fade animation to it

Comment: @benlevywebdesign hi, you can try jQuery `fadeIn()` function, something like in [this example here](http://jsfiddle.net/7txt3/24/) I added code: `$('#lrvinyl').hide().fadeIn();` but there might be a lot of variations how to do it. Also take a look at this page: [jQuery effects](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `rel="path_to_album_image"` to each play button.
And then add script:

```
$('#lrvinyl').css("background-image","url("+btn.attr('rel')+")");
```

So when you press play button the little image changes to image that is defined in play buttons `rel=""` attribute.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7txt3/21/)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the background image of your `#lrvinyl` div to the new image, like so:

```
$('#lrvinyl').css({'background-image':'url(http://benlevywebdesign.com/somafm/images/lush.png)'});
```

See the working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/7txt3/22/)

**UPDATE**:
Now this is the code to change the image dynamically, without hardcoding it like my previous code, check it:

```
var im = $(this).parent().next('div').css('background-image');
$('#lrvinyl').css({'background-image':im});
```

See the live [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/7txt3/23/)

Comment: @benlevywebdesign I've updated my answer with new code that I think is what you want, the image url is retrieve automatically instead of hardcoded.

Comment: almost but it doesn't use the smaller image